# Logging to local syslog inside centos7 container

Tags: docker, rsyslog

I would like my centos7 container to log message to /var/log/messages

```
[root@gen-r-vrt-057-009 ~]# docker exec -it rsyslog_base_centos7 "/bin/bash"
[root@gen-r-vrt-057-009 /]# logger "lior"
[root@gen-r-vrt-057-009 /]# cat /var/log/messages
[root@gen-r-vrt-057-009 /]#
```

I installed rsyslog, tried running container in several ways:

```
docker run -dit --name rsyslog_base_centos7 --network host  --privileged rsyslog/rsyslog_base_centos7:latest /usr/sbin/init
docker run -dit --name rsyslog_base_centos7  --log-driver=syslog  --network host  --privileged rsyslog/rsyslog_base_centos7:latest /usr/sbin/init
docker run -dit --name rsyslog_base_centos7  --log-driver=syslog  --network host -v /dev/log:/dev/log --privileged rsyslog/rsyslog_base_centos7:latest /usr/sbin/init
```

But nothing seems to do the trick.

Container os and docker version:

```
 [root@gen-r-vrt-057-009 /]# cat /etc/redhat-release
 CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)
 [root@gen-r-vrt-057-009 /]# exit
 [root@gen-r-vrt-057-009 ~]# docker -v
 Docker version 17.03.2-ce, build f5ec1e2
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to run rsyslog inside the container but want to make rsyslog log data from the host machine. By default, this is not possible due to isolation.

It is an interesting use case, and we probably should add an issue tracker at https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog-docker.

You can probably achieve your goal by mounting /dev/log into the container, but depending on the host OS that requires some extra work there as well.

The rsyslog/rsyslog_base_centos7 is designed with the intent to provide a base container that you can use to make applications **inside** the container use rsyslog logging.

Please also have a look at this Twitter conversation: https://twitter.com/rgerhards/status/978183898776686592 - doc updates will be upcoming once we have the actual procedure.

*Note: This answer was completely rewritten as I originally totally missed the point.*

Answer (score 1):

Smart people from rsyslog put the following Docker image together:
https://hub.docker.com/r/rsyslog/rsyslog_base_centos7
It allows for your use case :

> c) want to run a client machine where rsyslog processes log messagesv
>   (the default CentOS 7 config does NOT work inside a container, but
>   this container has a corrected config!)

Here is a URL to a patch you can throw to CentOS7 docker config to make it work:
https://gist.github.com/oleksandriegorov/2718a7e35b8d17ada934b651d627ab97

Of course, restart rsyslogd to apply changes.

Comment: I have not tried CentOS8, yet. Once I am there - will give it a try.